# Is there any value in using ClamAV to scan the entire filesystem and/or run as root?

Tags: antivirus, clamav, headless

I am setting up a headless server that'll be hosting SAMBA for my LAN and a web accessible website.

ClamAV seems to be the defacto standard for Linux anti-virus. Most articles I read online talk about scanning `/home` but wouldn't it make sense to set up a cron-job to scan **everything** from `/` down?

And, since ClamAV runs as as its own user, how does it get access to files in `/home` since it doesn't own them? Or do I need to have `clamav-daemon` run as root?

Comment: clamscan runs as the user that starts it, not as its own user. I don't know if there is any reason not to scan root, but I would probably exclude directories like /dev or /sys from the scan.

Comment: What I am stuck on is how to have a daily cron job scan various folders of other user's for viruses?